# Hierarchical CheckBox Not showing properly

Tags: html, jquery, flask

I am following the below link:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/hierarchical-checkbox-tree.html

Created a flask app:

```
|-- static
|   |-- hierarchical-checkboxes.css
|   `-- hierarchical-checkboxes.js
|-- templates
|   |-- ssr.html
`-- ui_server.py
```

ssr.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
   <head>
      <title>SSR</title>
      <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='hierarchical-checkboxes.css') }}">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
      </script>

      <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='hierarchical-checkboxes.js')}}">
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="hierarchy-checkboxes" rel="example">
         <input class="hierarchy-root-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
         <label class="hierarchy-root-label">Root</label>
         <div class="hierarchy-root-child hierarchy-node">
            <div class="hierarchy-node">
               <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
               <label class="hierarchy-label">Node</label>
               <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
                  <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
               </div>
               <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
                  <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
               </div>
               <div class="hierarchy-node">
                  <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="hierarchy-label">Node</label>
                  <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
                     <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                     <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
                     <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                     <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
                     <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                     <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
                  <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
               <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
               <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
               <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
               <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="hierarchy-node leaf">
               <input class="hierarchy-checkbox" type="checkbox">
               <label class="hierarchy-label">Node (Leaf)</label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

ui_server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
import requests
import json

@app.route("/ssr", methods=['GET'])
def ssr():
    return render_template('ssr.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000)
```

The problem is that, although I am seeing the treeview, the "+" buttons are missing, seeing like below:
[image]

***I am new to this and need some help here!***

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample project link, I think the problem is you don't have 'collapse.png' file in your folder. If you look at the css file it's using this image to show the plus button.